# Is there a way to render React components imperatively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React application, I would like to render a DOM tree to a canvas or PDF.

The DOM tree isn't the active component but is instead available in a variable inside a function within the route.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Summary(props) {

  function SaveForm(){
    const obj = <div>I am what is saved</div>
    const obj_as_blob = ...code to save obj as canvas/pdf/blob...
    axios.post('/save',obj_as_blob)
      .then((resp)=>{console.log(resp)})
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am what the user sees</p>
      <button onClick={SaveForm}>Send File to backend</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Many libraries I have found such as [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) only allow imperative access to elements attached to the current document, alternatives like [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) require limited use of their components and won't allow me to use my components in the render step.

The final intent is to take the `obj` as a rendered blob and send it to a back end server for saving. This is then given to the user at a later date.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't know where put the code to query a specific DOM to convert?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Imagine that they will have a submission button and whilst they are submitting I will asynchronously render the `<div>I am what is saved</div>` to a pdf and HTTP POST it to a back end server.

Comment: To be honest I don't fully get you well. Is that a callback called as you clicked on the button to do convert + submit your file?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I've changed by example, does that help?

Comment: can't you just render it in an html which is hidden and save its content after that?

Comment: or you just send the file to server and server will save its html by converting the pdf into html?

Comment: @yash The libraries I've tried don't render hidden content as its hidden. Could you elaborate on the second example as to how I would get the file to post to the server?

Comment: do you get the file object from props?

Comment: No, I have to generate it into the `obj` constant inside the `SaveForm()` function. `obj` will be an arbitrary JSX element that needs to be send to the backend.

Comment: one thing, you want to convert pdf to html, right? not sure if it's possible though

Comment: No the goal state is pdf. I'm happy with any other format though as the backend can do the x to pdf conversion as necessary.

The trick is actually getting the blob to post to the backend.

Comment: if you just want the whole page as an HTML string do this `const obj = document.body.outerHTML;`
The JSX code doesn't actually exist in the browser, since browsers don't know how to render JSX. It gets converted to JS code when you build your project, then the resulting JS code will modify the DOM at runtime. You can always capture a snapshot of the current DOM using regular old JS code.

Comment: Of course you can capture only a specific element and its children if you have access to an element. You can use a ref to get access to a specific element. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html then you can use .outerHTML to get that element + its children as a string to send to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for you as before you capture your jsx element, you would put to the anchor in your active component, then you unmount it as you sent the snapshot to your backend:

```js
function Summary(props) {

  const yourAnchor = React.useRef();


  function save() {
    const obj = <div>I am what is saved</div>;

    ReactDOM.render(obj, yourAnchor.target, () => {
      // your jsx finally attached to the document
      const obj_as_blob = ...code to save obj as canvas/pdf/blob...

      axios.post('/save',obj_as_blob)
       .finally(() => {
         // Unmount the node
         ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(yourAnchor.current);
       })
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={yourAnchor} />
      <p>I am what the user sees</p>
      <button onClick={save}>Send File to backend</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```